# NoMethodError: undefined method `key_columns' for #<Class:0x00000007863dd0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, cassandra, cequel

I'm new at rails and also cequel. I have existing model witch was genearted on Postgres and now i'm trying to migrate it to the Cassandra. 
1. I would just like to migrate one of my model and other i would like to leave on Postgres. Is this possible?

My models:

```
class TripPoint
  include Cequel::Record
  belongs_to :trip
  key     :device_created_at, :timestamp
  key     :trip_points_id, :timeuuid, auto: true
  column  :rssi, :int
  ....
end

class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trip_points

end
```

When i try to run: rake cequel:migrate
I'm getting the error:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `key_columns' for #<Class:0x00000007863dd0>
/home/zmagajna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
/home/zmagajna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cequel-1.7.0/lib/cequel/record/associations.rb:117:in `belongs_to'
/home/zmagajna/Ruby/ULU/ulu-rails/app/models/trip_point.rb:10:in `<class:TripPoint>'
/home/zmagajna/Ruby/ULU/ulu-rails/app/models/trip_point.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/zmagajna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
/home/zmagajna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
/home/zmagajna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
/home/zmagajna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
/home/zmagajna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
/home/zmagajna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:307:in `depend_on'
/home/zmagajna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
/home/zmagajna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cequel-1.7.0/lib/cequel/record/tasks.rb:61:in `block in migrate'
/home/zmagajna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cequel-1.7.0/lib/cequel/record/tasks.rb:55:in `each'
/home/zmagajna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cequel-1.7.0/lib/cequel/record/tasks.rb:55:in `migrate'
/home/zmagajna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/cequel-1.7.0/lib/cequel/record/tasks.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/zmagajna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/zmagajna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => cequel:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My environment:
ruby 2.1.2p95
Rails 4.1.10
cequel (= 1.7.0)

Comment: I think your `Trip` class should also `include Cequel::Record`

Comment: But Trip should not be table in Cassandra, it should stay as Postgres table.